# How to improve performance when converting to string and trimming?

Tags: c#, performance

I have the following function that is called repeatedly millions of times within my import utility application:

```
public static string SafeTrim(object str) {
   if ( str == null || str == DBNull.Value )
      return string.Empty;
   else
      return str.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Because it's so heavily used and called so frequently, I want to make sure that performance is optimized. A very common use case is passing in a `DataTable` column value, thusly:

```
pseudocode: SafeTrim(DataTable->Row->Column->Value);
```

Because a column value is an object rather than a string, I need to do the object check. And it can often be `DBNull.Value` as well.

Is there anything I can do to make my `SafeTrim()` function more performant?

Comment: Have you profiled your application to determine whether this is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: All string operations create a new string object so `ToString().Trim()` *could* be a performance bottleneck if its executed thousands of times. The best way to avoid this is to *not* use `ToString()` and `Trim()` blindly. The default formats for the built-in types don't need trimming. Whitespace would appear only if `str` was already a string. In this case `ToString()` would act as a no-op. You could remove it if you checked the type of the `str` parameter

Comment: If performance is really an issue you should investigate `ReadOnlySpan<char>` in .NET Core 2.2+. Operations like [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.trim?view=netcore-2.2) don't allocate new temporary objects

Comment: If possible you should *avoid* loading everything into a big DataTable. If your import target is a database like SQL Server or MySQL you could use their bulk import classes like SqlBulkCopy to read data from an IDataReader. CsvHelper can expose its data through the CsvDataReader class.

Comment: >> "In this case `ToString()` would act as a no-op. You could remove it if you checked the type of the `str` parameter." Question: Since the input type is `object` and the return type is string, when the incoming object is already a string, how can I avoid `ToString()` and save CPU cycles, while still returning a string? Even if a `string` comes in as an object, I still have to convert that `object` to a string somehow before return the string value.

Comment: Something like `return (str is string stringStr) ? stringStr.Trim() : str.ToString();` or for older versions of C#, `return (str is string) ? ((string)str).Trim() : str.ToString();`